# How does the Bitdefender Box actually work?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, security, malware

As I'm gradually adding internet-connected devices, appliances, and "things" around the house, I've been looking for one solution to protect all of them from malware and unwanted intrusions.

As of right now,  it looks like the [Bitdefender Box](http://www.bitdefender.com/box/) is the only product on the market that can not only protect my PC and mobile devices, but also "internet of things" devices like smart TVs, smart thermostats, etc.

However, their website and the [reviews](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2477677,00.asp) that I've been able to find don't really elaborate much on how exactly this protection works. It seems like you can install apps onto your smartphone, tablet, and PC that will do local virus scans, but for connected devices that don't run mainstream operating systems or aren't user-configurable, what is it doing? Is it a glorified firewall? Does it scan all traffic for malicious malware downloads and suspicious activity?

How does it protect every single possible device that can connect to a home network when there are so many different possibilities?

Comment: I typed "bitdefender box review" into google and skimmed one review, it pretty much handled your questions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't own one personally, but the gist of how it works is clear.

The system acts as a black box, a network infusion detector and a central hub for communication between PCs.

A black box (or honey pot) is a device usually connected to a network that passively waits for connections to its systems. A normal user would never usually access the box, but automated viruses will. The system will analyze the access pattern, cross checking it with BitDefender and narrowing down the options that are available for the specific malware.

The NIDS piece usually uses heuristics along with provided data (from BitDefender) that knows when a device is acting out of line and can disconnect connections before they happen to compromise a system that may or may not have malware protection (ex. an IoT device). The Box seems to have a simplified version.

As for communications between PCs, it can use software based scanning to detect issues and if one is found, disconnect it from the network before it can cause harm to another system.

(Please note that most of this is generic assumptions and should be cleared up with a more detailed analysis of the device)